# How to hide base method from Base Class?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

i developed some codes to test.i know : if i use internal method , we can hide my method  in another namespace forexample:

[public vs. internal methods on an internal class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711361/public-vs-internal-methods-on-an-internal-class)

how to hide Add method in  Main program;if i ress dot(.) intellisense show me Add method in Base method. i dont want to see add method to derive a instance from MyClass1?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MyDb;
```

namespace BaseClassUygulamasi
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new MyClass1().Save("123456789", "ali.yilmaz");
        }
    }
}

namespace MyDb
{

```
public  abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    private Dictionary&#60;string, string&#62; dic { get; set; }

    public MyBaseClass()
    {

    }

    internal void Add(string key, string value)
    {
        dic.Add(key, value);
    }
}


public class MyClass1 : MyBaseClass
{
    public MyClass1()
        : base()
    {

    }

    public void Save(string TCKimlikNo, string AdSoyAd)
    {
        base.Add(TCKimlikNo, AdSoyAd);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: internal is for assembly and not for namespace !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want classes that inherit from your base class to have access to the `Add(...)` method, but nothing external to that, then you need to mark it as `protected`, such that:

```
public  abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> dic { get; set; }

    public MyBaseClass()
    {

    }

    protected void Add(string key, string value)
    {
        dic.Add(key, value);
    }
}


public class MyClass1 : MyBaseClass
{
    public MyClass1()
        : base()
    {

    }

    public void Save(string TCKimlikNo, string AdSoyAd)
    {
        base.Add(TCKimlikNo, AdSoyAd);
    }
}
```

This way, only classes that inherit from `MyBaseClass` will be able to access `Add(...)`.

Answer (score 4):

Make the `Add` method [`protected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) instead of `internal`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wanting to use the Protected keyword instead of internal.